# How to draw a sprite from a char array using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, jframe

So, basically I'm trying to use a char array for a character sprite for my game prototype right now, but I cannot find a working way to read each element in the correct 'row' to print out the character (trying to find a way to draw the sprite by using fill rects line by line of arrays). Again, I've tried many ways such as `if (i % 5 == 0) y_temp += 5;` for "indenting" to fill rectangles of the sprite on a new row, but none of it is working.
Suggestions/help anyone?

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;

public class test extends JFrame {
    private int x_pos, y_pos;
    private JFrame frame;
    private draw dr;
    private char[] WARRIOR;
    private Container con;
    public test() {
        x_pos = y_pos = 200;
        frame = new JFrame("StixRPG");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        con = frame.getContentPane();
        con.setBackground(Color.black);
        dr = new draw();
        dr.setBackground(Color.black);
        con.add(dr);
        WARRIOR = (
      " " +
        "!!!!!" +
        "!!ooo" +
        "!!!!!" +
        "#####" +
        "#####" +
        "#####" +
        "** **").toCharArray();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test tst = new test();
    }
    class draw extends JPanel { 
        public draw() {
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponents(g);
             int y_temp = y_pos;
            for (int i = 0; i < WARRIOR.length; i++) {
                 if (WARRIOR[i] == '!') {
                     g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 204));
                    g.fillRect(x_pos+i*5, y_temp, 5, 5);
                }
                else if (WARRIOR[i] == 'o') {
                    g.setColor(new Color(204, 0, 0));
                    g.fillRect(x_pos+i*5, y_temp, 5, 5);
                }
                else if (WARRIOR[i] == '#') {
                    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 102));
                    g.fillRect(x_pos+i*5, y_temp, 5, 5);
                }
                else if (WARRIOR[i] == '*') {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                     g.fillRect(x_pos+i*5, y_temp, 5, 5);
                }
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Some best practice suggestions: class names should begin with a capital letter, and uppercase words should be reserved for constants (static final).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,  you should get the right coordinates like this: `x = i % 5; y = i / 5;`. So then, you can `fillRect(x*5, y*5, 5, 5);`.

**EDIT:** I just saw that additional space. This means you will have to subtract one first:
`x = (i-1) % 5; y = (i-1) / 5;`

**EDIT 2:** Yeah, and then of course you will have to add `y_pos` and `x_pos`: `fillRect(x_pos + x*5, y_pos + y*5, 5, 5);`

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you, I actually got most of the sprite to display except for the last element on each 'row' by using if        (i % 5 == 0) {
          y_temp += 5;
          x_temp -= 25;
         }
         else
           g.fillRect(x_temp+i*5, y_temp, 5, 5);                                         This within the char if statements. but I'll try your (awesome/clever) method!

Comment: Also, I think computing x and y from scratch every time (instead of summing them up) make the code easier to read and less error-prone.

Comment: Btw, don't forget to accept an answer once you got your problem solved.

Comment: Holy crap! I love you! It works FLAWLESSLY now! Just a question, though, the value x is determining if the "row" is getting to big/exceeding bounds and the y variable is for the total columns, right? Thanks :DDDD

Comment: Yes, kind of. `i % 5` computes what is left if you subtract 5 from `i` as many times as you can. For example, `12 % 5` gives you 2, since that's what's left after you subtract 5 from 12 twice. Does that help you understanding it?

Comment: Yes, I understand how modulo operations. But thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = (i-1)%5;
int y = (i-1)/5;

fillRect( x_pos + x*5, y_pos + y*5, 5, 5 );
```

*Note that it is important to divide then multiply because

```
n (not always)== (n/5)*5
```

in integer arithmetic.